# TeamCity Custom Build Number - AssemblyInfo patcher

Tags: powershell, teamcity, build-process

I have created a TeamCity build configuration which suits my needs, see build log below:

[image: Build Log]

It's all working great except for 1 thing - **Custom Build Number**. My build number format is as follows:

- Major.Minor.BuildCounter.TodaysDate, i.e. 2.0.59.20160224.
- I achieved this with a PowerShell script.

Notice in the build log, **Step 1** is to **Set Build Number**. Problem is that this happens after the **Update assembly versions** step. So this version number does not get applied to my assemblies.

But the correct version number is used everywhere else in the build process.

So my question is, HOW do I set the Custom Build Number before AssemblyInfo Patcher runs?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**Resolved using Snapshot dependency feature of TeamCity.**

Created a build configuration called Version. This has a powershell script build step which creates my desired build number.

Next, I make my actual build configuration dependent on the Version build configuration.

Then I get this build number in my actual build configuration, like so:
**%dep.[Build Configuration ID].system.build.number%**

Answer (score 1):

Teamcity provides build feature "AssemblyInfo Patcher" which  allows setting a build number to an assembly without having patch.
You may find it under :

Build Configuration Settings -> Build Features -> click on add new feature and select AssemblyInfo patcher.

[image]

You may assign same build number format "Major.Minor.BuildCounter.TodaysDate" AssemblyInfo Patcher. something like : %Major%.%Minor%.%build.counter%.%system.build.start.date%

By adding Major and Minor as teamcity configuration parameters.
You may use teamcity's predefined %build.counter% parameter.

And finally TodaysDate: 
 The [Groovy Plugin](https://confluence.jetbrains.com/display/TW/Groovy+plug) for TeamCity provides build start date/time properties

> system.build.start.date
>   system.build.start.time

Comment: I am already doing that. As per my build log, my build number is a custom formatted number. AssemblyPatcher runs before my custom build number is created.

Comment: my bad.. didn't look at build log. I've updated my answer. Hope it will help.